# How to create durable rubber feet to breadboards?

Tags: breadboard

I have purchased two cheap breadboards (one a long time ago, another recently). A large 4+7 configuration (4 main boards, 7 dual power strips) costs only around 35 EUR, whereas a decent 3M breadboard of the same size costs about 250 EUR.

The breadboards are not of particularly high quality, and the main problem is that they come with four separate rubber feet that have an adhesive surface. The theory is that whoever purchased the breadboard, will attach them to the metal plate of the breadboard. The practice is that after the breadboard has been used for a long time, all four of the rubber feet get lost because the adhesive is not strong enough to hold them permanently on the metal.

One possibility would be to use hot melt glue as a stronger glue -- perhaps it could keep the rubber feet attached (or perhaps not, as gluing things to smooth metal is not a very durable attachment method). However, if a breadboard is old and has already lost all four of its rubber feet, it may be impossible to find new rubber feet separately sold.

It is not an option to use the breadboard without the feet as the metal is not a completely flat surface, but there are screws extending below the metal: the screws holding the plastic breadboard segments in place, and the binding post screws.

I would like to create rubber feet to the breadboard that stay attached even if the breadboard is handled roughly, and have a high coefficient of friction on ordinary table surfaces. How can I do that?

Comment: Just attach the feet with polyurethane caulk. Save yourself an hour. Replacement rubber feet are very cheap.

Comment: How is that related to electronic design? Also, typical hardware store or supermarket can sell you a bag of rubber or silicone feet with a couple of euros.

Comment: "it may be impossible to find new rubber feet separately sold." It won't be. Rubber feet are easily available.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just go and buy some rubber feet from your local hardware store or from, say, Ebay and screw / glue them in place. If you buy the type that are sold for use on furniture legs you can be pretty certain that, if they can withstand being pushed across the floor on a chair, they will remain stuck to your breadboard. Total cost €2-3 plus the cost of the board. Time 5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Let us look at the properties required from the feet. Firstly, they should be at least about 8mm long, preferably not much longer than that (the feet I created are about 20mm long, a bit more than I would like, but not excessively long). Every foot must be exactly as long with 0.1mm precision so handmaking the rubber feet requires some way to ensure they have exactly the same length. They need not be entirely made of rubber, just the bottom surface needs to be rubber and permanently attached to the feet possibly made from other material. The attachment method to the breadboard preferably should be a screw because otherwise they will not stay permanently attached.

I decided to make the feet from 18mm glued laminated timber. The 18mm dimension is the length of the foot, so every foot will be precisely 18mm +/-0.1mm. For the screws, I purchased 2.0mm minor diameter 2.9mm major diameter 13mm long countersink screws. I selected countersink because if I drill a hole larger than major diameter on the metal, the countersink keeps the small major diameter screw in the large hole centered. For the actual rubber on the feet, I decided to use an old broken bicycle inner tube.

Firstly, use an electric jigsaw to cut a 20mm wide bar from the 18mm thick glued laminated timber board. Then use a hacksaw to cut the 20mm wide bar into 20mm long segments. The 20mm dimension is not critical: if a single piece 23mm wide and 26mm long it won't cause any harm. Only the 18mm thickness dimension is important.

Then drill four holes with a diameter larger than major diameter of the screws to all four corners of the metal plate with a metal drill bit. You may need to file away the burrs from the bottom surface of the holes after drilling.

Then drill four partial holes significantly smaller than screw minor diameter in all four ~20mm x ~20mm x 18mm pieces of wood. The idea is that the hole is drilled in the ~20mm x ~20mm surface, so the 18mm exact thickness becomes the length of the feet. For my 2.0mm minor diameter screws, I drilled partial holes of 1.5mm. In this case, you must be careful to attach the very small drill bit centered to the drill chuck, and also to not damage the very small drill bit when drilling.

If the bottom of the metal plate has screw heads that interfere with the ~20mm x ~20mm flat surface of the pieces of wood, preventing it to be parallel to the metal plate when screwing it in, use a rotary tool such as Dremel to carve the wood slightly to create room for the small screw heads. My breadboard had screws interfering with two of the four feet, so I needed to carve two of the feet slightly.

Then screw all four of the wood feet in. Test the wood feet on a flat surface such as a table to ensure that all four feet of the breadboard are in contact with the table. Mine was perfect, although I noticed the coefficient of friction of the wood feet against a wood table was not satisfactory, so the breadboard is not usable yet.

Warm up a hot glue gun. While it's warming, cut four ~40mm x ~40mm pieces of a broken old bicycle inner tube. Use sections that are free of patches. All four pieces should be from the same tube to ensure they are the same thickness. Investigate the tube: the inside of the tube should be quite slippery due to having lots of talcum powder inside to prevent it from sticking to itself on the inside, but the outside surface of the tube should have a high coefficient of friction against a table. Because the outside surface of the tube has better coefficient of friction, you will glue the inside surface against the wood feet.

Once the hot glue gun has warmed up, attach the four pieces of inner tube to the wood feet with hot melt glue. Remember to press the breadboard hard against a flat surface such as a table at the glued inner tube area, so that the inner tube becomes flat and stays well attached to the wood feet. Do one inner tube piece at a time.

After all four pieces have been glued, and the hot glue has cooled down, use scissors to cut the ~40mm x ~40mm glued pieces to the same size as the wood feet.

After this, test the breadboard on a flat surface such as a table. My Chinese breadboard now has four durable feet, all of them touch the table at the same time, and the coefficient of friction against the table is probably even better than on a 3M breadboard.

Was this worth doing? Took about an hour to fix a breadboard, so if an hour of time is worth 20 EUR, a bicycle inner tube is worth 5 EUR per two breadboards (2.5 EUR per breadboard -- it's not free even if it's broken as it could have been patched), the screws cost 4 EUR per two breadboards (2 EUR per breadboard) and the hot melt glue and wood are used so little they are practically free, the total cost of a Chinese breadboard is 35 EUR + 20 EUR + 2.5 EUR + 2 EUR = 59.5 EUR, still far less than 250 EUR of a 3M breadboard of the same size. So I'd say this was worth doing.